# Searching for a synonym or an alternate Phrase

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, synonyms, catch-phrases

I am looking for a synonym or a phrase that means, that

> after reading a particular thought my perspective / way to look at life has changed in a good manner.

Basically this is for my new blog name, it will be a collection of good quotes from/for life…

I was not able to find a good one, as most of the blog names are already taken, so looking for a different one...

Comment: I was thinking about "Mind Migrator" is it a good one?

Answer (score 1):

What about *Positive Reflections*?

Comment: yes this is good

Comment: but this one is already taken :(

Comment: Ooh, must've been good, then ;-)

Answer (score 1):

[*epiphany*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epiphany) seems to be a single word that might fit the bill. But I think Mr. long's suggestion is better for a blog name.

Comment: Perhaps *Epiphanic Excerpts*?